# Django accepting Chinese pseudo letters in email fields

Tags: django, validation, email, unicode, chinese-locale

There is a set of letters (A-Za-z), which Chinese users sometimes input where we expect ascii letters - but those are actually special characters defined in Unicode. Take a look at this sample email address:

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email

email = u'dummy@ｒａｙｓｆｉｒｓｔ．ｃｏｍ'

try:
    validate_email(email)
except ValidationError as e:
    print "oops! wrong email"
else:
    print "hooray! email is valid"
```

Sure, we can read the address. However, such an email address makes a lot of trouble in various scenarios. Typical email servers appear not to be able to handle such characters. Is this a Django bug? What's the best way to detect such letters in Python? Or better even, is there a flag for Django in order to forbid such letters in `validate_email`?

**Update:** In the meantime, I found out that such characters are likely allowed in email addresses, however support for them is so-so and they are causing a lot of trouble. Even real Chinese/Japanese/Korean characters as well as umlauts are allowed per definition. So, technically, it doesn't look like a Django bug, although it is very inconvenient at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience, the IME used to enter Chinese characters is easy to switch into "full width" mode and causes full width latin characters to be entered.  You could use `str.translate` to revert them to non-full width, but as you pointed out, the full width characters could be valid:

```
#coding:utf8
import unicodedata as ud

# Build a translation table of fullwidth to non-fullwidth characters.
table = {}
for i in range(65536):
    try:
        name = ud.name(chr(i))
        if name.startswith('FULLWIDTH '):
            other = ud.lookup(name[10:])
            table[i] = ord(other)
    except ValueError:
        pass

email = u'dummy@ｒａｙｓｆｉｒｓｔ．ｃｏｍ'
print(email)
print(email.translate(table))
```

Output:

```
dummy@ｒａｙｓｆｉｒｓｔ．ｃｏｍ
dummy@raysfirst.com
```

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, because it does show possible solutions. I was actually more looking for a way to tell Django to do that automatically. There is, by the way, a much shorter and probably more efficient way for the translation: `unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', email)`